# Why do we call lambdas anonymous functions?

Tags: ruby, lambda

I named a lambda `lamb`:

```
lamb = lambda { |name| "hello #{name}"}
lamb.call("Steve") # => "hello Steve"
```

Since I gave the function a name, it is no longer anonymous. Why do we call it anonymous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out already, whether you assign the lambda to a variable or not does not really change the fact that the lambda itself is not named. Look at the difference between how a method object behaves vs a lambda:

```
def test; end
mt = method(:test)
#=> #<Method: Object#test>
mt.arity
#=> 0
mt.name
#=> :test
l = -> {}
l.arity
#=> 0
l.name
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for #<Proc:0x007faef08319f8@(irb):13 (lambda)>
```

As you can see, for a method the name is an inherent part of the method object, for a lambda it is not. What the lambda expression returns is an anonymous function that you then assign to a variable. This is not really different from assigning `sum = 1 + 2`, where the expression on the right has no inherent connection to the name its assigned to. This is also illustrated by the fact that it's perfectly possible to call a lambda without giving it a name first:

```
x = 1
->{x+1}.()
#=> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas/procs are only *anonymous* if they're unnamed, e.g.:

```
# anonymous lambda
[1,2,3].map(&lambda {|x| x * x})

# named lambda
square = lambda {|x| x * x} 
[1,2,3].map(&square)
```

Comment: This does not mean that your lambda is named `square` though. If you assign `square = 3 * 3` on the next line you have no reference pointing at your lambda anymore.

Comment: Would you still refer to _the anonymous squaring function_ as an "anonymous function" while it's referenced by `square`, though? Also, your redefinition example only works because of Ruby's dynamic nature. The same example would not work in a statically typed language like Haskell. (I realize this post is tagged with Ruby, but I think the question/answer are more broadly applicable.) Great answer, BTW. :)

Comment: I'd probably refer to it as the "lambda stored in square" or "the squaring lambda". It doesn't really matter if the language is dynamic or static, the name is never the name of the lambda, it's the name of a memory location referencing said lambda. Some languages use different namespaces for functions and variables, this difference is meaningful there (i.e. in Common Lisp you'd have to use `#'square` to `map` the function over a list, but can just use `square` for a lambda referenced by a variable). But yeah, semantics ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

The lambda in your example is anonymous. "lamb" is not the name of your lambda, it is the name of a local variable whose value is an anonymous lambda method.

The variable does not name the lambda any more than x = 42 results in a named number.

Contrast this with methods in a class. They are named as part of adding them to a class or module.